# Did John Woo invent the flying-double-pistol-jump?

Tags: first-appearance, action, stunts

[image: two pistol leap]

As an example of this stunt, see the image of Chow Yun-fat performing the stunt in *Hard-Boiled*.

Did John Woo invent the action movie stunt of a person doing a flying leap through the air while firing two pistols? Or did he merely popularize it?